# How to use Jekyll code in (inline) code highlighting?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

How can I use for example `{{ post.date | date: "%H:%M %p - %-d %b %y" }}` in code highlighting?

The only way I have found so far is using `{% raw %}{{ post.date | date: "%H:%M %p - %-d %b %y" }}{% endraw %}`. However, then it shows the code snippet as unformatted text rather than with proper inline code highlighting.

If I use

```
`{{ post.date | date: "%H:%M %p - %-d %b %y" }}`
```

then the code is rendered instead of shown as code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{% highlight html %}
{% raw %}
  {% include google_analytics.html %}
{% endraw %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: Why is this accepted?  This looks like block highlighting to me.

Comment: this throws an unknown tag error (though it still worked) for me. I ended up just using {% highlight %}

Answer (score 2):

That is how I do it.

Check it out live:
http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2013/11/05/makingmostdatadirectory.html

```
{% highlight html %}
{% raw %} 
{% for project in site.data.projects %}

    {% if project.publish == true %}
        <strong><a href="/projects/{{ project.project }}.html">{{ project.project }}</a></strong>

        <span class="tag-project">{{ project.category }}</span>
        {{ project.description }}
        <hr/>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endraw %} 
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: This works for block code highlighting. But how do you highlight Jekyll code inline that would be otherwise rendered?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that easily by combining {% highlight %} and {% raw %}
 for example

```
{% highlight ruby %}
{% raw %}
        ---
        limit: 100
        ---

        {% for post in site.posts limit: page.limit %}

            {
              "title": "{{ post.title }}",
              "date"     : "{{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}",

              "excerpt" : "{{ post.excerpt }}",
              {% if post.categories %} "categories"  : [
                {% for category in post.categories %} "{{ category }}"
                {% if forloop.last %}{% else %},{% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                ],
              {% endif %}
              {% if post.categories == nil %} "categories"  : [],  {% endif %}
              "url": "{{ post.url }}",
              {% if post.tags %} "tags"  : [
                {% for tag in post.tags %} "{{ tag }}"
                {% if forloop.last %}{% else %},{% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                ]
              {% endif %}
              {% if post.tags == nil %} "tags"  : []  {% endif %}

            }

            {% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}

        {% endfor %}
{% endraw %}
{% endhighlight %}
```